# How to write a test case to check cyclic on_off of an alarm in Vtest Studio

Tags: automation

I want to write a test case in Vtest Studio to test a cyclic behavior of alarm retriggering.
once the alarm is triggered with a source,a  Lin Signal is set to ON for a period of time and off for a period of time.

I want to do it with For loop but don't know how to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.